# Poisson probability or binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics

> "In an experiment, the mean number of particle deflections per beam collision is 12. What is the probability that there will be 4 or less deflections per beam collision?"

I don't think it's Poisson because the deflections don't depend on the number of trials. But at the same time I don't think it's binomial because there's no probability of a successful measurement.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem outside of those two methods, help?

*EDIT: What if I take the st.dev of the mean to be the square root of the mean? Can I do that and then perform a z-test?

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information here.  We have no idea what the distribution of the length of a string is.  Is there some context you're not telling us?

Comment: I changed the question to avoid a textbook copy and paste but a more accurate rephrasing would be: "In an experiment, the mean number of particle deflections per beam collision is 12. What is the probability that there will be 4 or less deflections per beam collision?"

Comment: It's still not enough information, unless you have a probability model of what happens in a beam collision.